# NPM Local Path (Dependency) Transitive Dependency Omitted?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I use a very simple NPM project with a chain with one local dependency that has its own dependency (regular package `fs-extra`).

`root` -> `file:../local-dependency` -> `fs-extra`

Very strange things happen (NPM version `6.14.8`) when I run `npm install`, I recognized that when:

a) local dependency (of root) points to parent or "higher" directory (e.g. `file:../local-dependency`), its transitive dependencies (`fs-extra`) **are NOT** installed to `node_modules` of root

b) local dependency (of root) points to the directory on same level as root (`file:./local-dependency`), its transitive dependencies (`fs-extra`) **are** installed to `node_modules` of root

Is this something normal or is it a (known) bug? Current behavior seems very strange to me.